# How to use fstream, to write different values in a .txt file

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling, ofstream

The problem I am facing is the following: 
if we define something like

```
ofstream myFile; 

    myFile.open("Directory//debug.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
     myFile << i << endl;
     myFile.close(); 
    }
```

the output in the debug file will be 9. 
I want to make it so that it outputs all the numbers from 0 to 9. Aside from closing the file after the `for` statement is it possible to define an ofstream that would do that?

Comment: *Why* do you want to close the stream inside the loop? And are you averse to *opening* it inside the loop?

Comment: After the first write, you're writing to a closed file. This is not allowed. Why wouldn't you close the file after the for loop?

Comment: So you want to close within the loop, do you mind reopening the file inside the loop as well ?

Comment: I don't mind reopening inside the loop at all. 
 
The set up I have is I am calling a function `foo` repeatedly in a function `goo` I create the file in `foo` and I want to output a new value each time `foo` is called in `goo` So that's why I want to close it also inside `foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have two options:

Close the file outside the loop:

```
myFile.open("Directory//debug.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myFile << i << endl;
}
myFile.close();
```

or open the file in append mode and close inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myFile.open("Directory//debug.txt", ios_base::app);
    myFile << i << endl;
    myFile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: The set up I have is I am calling a function `foo` repeatedly in a function `goo` I create the file in `foo` and I want to output a new value each time `foo` is called in `goo`

Comment: Opening in append mode sounds like exactly what I need, can you also provide the syntax? I know I could search, but still.

Comment: @sjsam I am sure it does output a new value of `i`. I mean I just tested it. Both versions work, i.e. with static variable and just opening in append mode.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan  :   For every call of  `foo` this one opens and closes the file 10 times.. For the overhead alone, I won't chose this one. Plus the logic simply doesn't seem right for me.  For every call of  `foo` you append 10 values to the file in question. That is not clearly what you need.

Comment: I see, you misunderstood the set-up. Disregard the `for` example for a moment. The `foo` function opens a file only once when it's called, but it's called several times. The `for` thing was simply to emulate the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
myFile.close();
```

should be put after the for-loop. Also introduce some error checking to see if the `open` was indeed a success.

> I am calling a function foo repeatedly in a function goo I create the
>   file in foo and I want to output a new value each time foo is called
>   in goo.

In order to achieve your objective you could use a static variable inside `foo`

```
void foo()
{
static int count=0;    
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("Directory//debug.txt",std::fstream::app)

if (myfile.is_open()) // Checking is file is successfully opened.
{
  count++;
  myfile<<count<<"\n";
}
myfile.close; // Close the file
}
```

Comment: The set up I have is I am calling a function foo repeatedly in a function goo I create the file in foo and I want to output a new value each time foo is called in goo. Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: Thank you. This is also a good solution, it's a shame I can't accept two answers @owacoder's answer was closer to what I imagined so I accepted that.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan : Also, you need to introduce some error checking, Also the for-loop with your original solution is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Error checking is there in my original code, the example with the `for` loop was a toy example to show exactly what the expected output is. Thanks.